# Command execution with Danf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, command, danf

I would like to execute some commands with [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) in order to use my sequencing and my services. Is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to handle commands easily in version **0.3.x** of Danf.

However, you are a lucky, an event of type command is coming in the version **0.4.0** which should be here in the next few weeks.
You would then be able to plug your sequences on an event of type command as for HTTP requests or DOM events.

*Note that socket events will also be available if you want to make some "real time" programming!*

> Version **0.4.0** should allow you to make performant and scalable single page web applications, real time web applications, mix of both, API and commands with only one framework.
>   Watch for the [danf repository on github](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) to be informed of releases.